# Java method that returns sum of number series and takes series array as parameter

Tags: java

I have tried this:

```
public class NumberSeries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this line of code is not correct
        SumOfNumbers( int nums [{23,44,12,33}]);
    }

    public static int SumOfNumbers(int Series[]) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Series.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + Series[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I am failing to call `SumOfNumbers` method correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Object instantiation is your problem.

Comment: basicly the syntax, you need to call it as `new int[]{23,44,12,33}`

Comment: If you'd use varargs you could change the method to `public static int sumOfNumbers(int... series )` and call it like `sumOfNumbers(23,44,12,33);`. Btw, the Java world likes variable and method names to start with a lower case character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is declaring an  in-line inline array.

```
SumOfNumbers( int nums [{23,44,12,33}]);
```

That should be

```
SumOfNumbers( new int [] {23,44,12,33}); // in-line passing
```

or even clear

```
int[] nums = new int[] {23,44,12,33}; // declaring
SumOfNumbers( nums); //passing
```

You are not declaring it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Not passing the array in correct way, modify code as following

```
int[] nums ={23,44,12,33};
SumOfNumbers( nums);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  int [] nums={23,44,12,33};

      SumOfNumbers( nums);
```

You can use this code in main method.